# Does the MessageDialog class for UWP Apps support three buttons on Mobile?

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I'm creating a simple program for reading text file on the Windows Phone. I decided to make it a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) App.

In the app, I have a very simple [MessageDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.aspx), with three options, Yes, No, Cancel. It works perfectly on the Desktop and in the Simulator. However, when testing with the actual device, the `ShowAsync` method fails with the message: "Value does not fall in the expected range".

This only happens if there are more than two commands registered in the dialog. Does the `MessageDialog` class really supports up to three commands - as the documentation suggests - or is this only applying for UWP Apps running on Desktop devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, there is a clear statement in the docs:

> The dialog has a command bar that can support up to 3 commands in desktop apps, or 2 commands in mobile apps.

Sad but true: on mobiles, there are two commands only. Need more? Use ContentDialog instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the documentation is missing information about Mobile (and really the API should do a better job here).

For Mobile, if you hit the Back key you get a `null` return value, so you can do this (*not recommended coding pattern, but best I can think of*):

```cs
async Task Test()
{
  const int YES = 1;
  const int NO = 2;
  const int CANCEL = 3;

  var dialog = new MessageDialog("test");
  dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "yes", Id = YES });
  dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "no", Id = NO });

  // Ugly hack; not really how it's supposed to be used.
  // TODO: Revisit if MessageDialog API is updated in future release
  var deviceFamily = AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily;
  if (deviceFamily.Contains("Desktop"))
  {
    dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "cancel", Id = CANCEL });
  }
  // Maybe Xbox 'B' button works, but I don't know so best to not do anything
  else if (!deviceFamily.Contains("Mobile"))
  {
    throw new Exception("Don't know how to show dialog for device "
      + deviceFamily);
  }

  // Will return null if you press Back on Mobile
  var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();

  // C# 6 syntactic sugar to avoid some null checks
  var id = (int)(result?.Id ?? CANCEL);

  Debug.WriteLine("You chose {0}", id);
}
```

Comment: That workaround works quite well. I ended up testing with `ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons") to test the existence of the hardware back button. Also, normally, I set the `CancelCommandIndex to the No or Cancel button. In the case of Windows Phone, I have to set it explicitly to `Int32.MaxValue.

Comment: Using the existence of that API is not much better; in theory it could be added to other device families that don't have back buttons, and I don't know whether other devices that don't have the API (like Xbox) support three buttons. There is no perfect solution but I think DeviceFamily is the best right now (whatever you do, keep the `TODO` in there!)